# Waiting for device when fastboot flash boot my google glass

Tags: android, google-glass

My google glass has not been updated.
I am trying it from last 10 days. 
I have followed all the steps given by google ( https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3226482?hl=en )

I have decided to boot my google glass

So,I followed doc (https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system) but i am stuck on below command

techno-30@techno-30:~/Dhims/SDKupdate/sdk/platform-tools$ sudo $(which fastboot) devices
015ECD7119006014        fastboot

techno-30@techno-30:~/Dhims/SDKupdate/sdk/platform-tools$ fastboot flash boot boot.img
< waiting for device >

i have tried two times but always waiting if device is connected.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

First put the Glass device into fastboot mode:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

Unlock the Glass device if locked:

```
fastboot oem unlock 
fastboot oem unlock
```

**(yes, you need to issue that command twice)**

[Optional] wipe the device- If the device was not locked (the above command will tell you) then you may want to wipe the user data partition to start clean, if so issue

```
fastboot -w
```

Then, Flash each of the partitions. Ex. For boot.img

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

I hope this will work. Tried my side working fine.